# Artefacts with SSAO in Three.js only on MacBook Pro (Retina)

Tags: three.js, ssao

I'm currently using the [SSAO shader provided in the Three.js examples](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader.js). It works perfectly on most of my machines aside from my MacBook Pro Retina. The MBP rendered SSAO perfectly until a few weeks ago (potentially after a firmware upgrade on the MBP).

As it stands, the MBP renders SSAO scenes with a huge amount of flickering artefacts all over the screen, like so:

[Scene code here](http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/#B/tRfbUts49Dn9Cm36UFOMHegy282FnTZc+gALQ+h0djp9UGw5VrElV5IJgeHf90iyHDs4ne1sywRb0rnf5fFvx5fTm3+uTlCq8uzoxdi+euOU4BjevXFOFEZRioUkatIvVbL3tm8AUq0yole9OY9X6FGvenMc3S4EL1m8F/GMiyF6OTB/IwPOsVhQNkTVlt8RkWR8OUQpjWPCzOmTZh467uOw0mSspVjBkaCFQlJEk36qVDEMw1zEnM+DBVVpOQ8inocqFYQEX2U4L2kWV9ucMjjqHwF7w0Oz+3GO5B7nRUZkCGuZ4pgIGU55sZqZ9TMBP4H7bPbucgv3/yeg4FIVgkdESsoW4UmSkEhNeQ7nP9eSDUHXhIExV1jKXyjkAsvbXyzCBqVTyFrO0Qud1mGIllzcYlMcKOECikrwnKB5uYD8t1pEPCbBgvNFRowORWiQaJmHVMoSdIihHGn2F40nbw7/fDt4Ge0faO40QR5aUhbzZUAZI+ITjVWKJpMJGqAd9NgFQwUWhKnG2aiF9oHQRao28OzhCD2ZAu4ZO3t3GKzBORHYRzIijPhImAgTMXJw3RWKeheTQqUXWBFBcebb7Q00B6J8FFX5NzJ+o4wqb8cQYkZzINE7vU1KFinKGbIo0IGMTk4yKM7IEt18uD45CT6R+dn5dQWp2NWYAbS2GX0gHR70uzxSkcc8KnPtGN2ZAlwUwG6aQrfxauuDmOcnGdFYjso8rLNaGl5BoRdQffSOTA3UQ38c+h1xCztU8tE+/KDNOilWQAB+pNpFwQPIOtRd2EBNjFrSZ/rEObZnYtWCX86/gm5vjp3rDIcAx2CrRW5aZ8JNILeVWLW4TMs5OasAHujrV/+OWhPmVVK0CC+ITN9jSSOXMh6kdDVgBvdJoicMekJOf11dHtLcKLAZjOA11u7Ri91dXQ9rZa1Q4P9MoFcb4a+1qjTtaYq1e++BGFRLA4EhNDkk42v0O6i0hw7c6NugWP0wxcN/pRBc4W6tOrGeadKJ9Ux6E0tGGBqWFtfYrtrbLvUh8rtov+Jk8simlAmHk2CeT+uAQSM17aKdb+bItmMQVCW12Z7T+WfUN/Drs/fv+ujLqE31kVFImFzWdO7go6KZDKKMQ2k0BQSlo3AJ12pn7cIyFM20TQRe6IZgIcMW4zbMR3A/UuS+C7MJ8ZFTaLhh0bokwGvt2dVoRlW/bendvgqsO1rdYNwlAQKm55/XoF1Pd8+Ng6rh7bQ9Zjv+tkZtoR463D/w7eMRwQ3ulGZKe8Pin1NGsLBnukwX3wNrp2DlYDobTs2J9VMrn4ixvyOU1qzqpL6XOXpLVifIZ/RKHWtLX6EvwR3OSt11G6ZvI5IwjWoSPZ7WXtguyfr4b7C3Ka2aBNoN3yc87aRLNshsHtzwWQS3IwZ4SpRkW0pUTmz49qk9ueuJvh7e3+CWo96Zc8A4FaCG5/CeRUnR3ORtAd8ROpIsIgHjS6+JZ/tKqylastdoEMDcOBh1oa020fYbLO30018vgsakUfetPrBxybCLjYpoXX3q4tjKn5VZtuHsiq0jrZ3cuIuOQ/vtBN9S+uvuXw==)
[image]

[Scene found here](http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/lego_ssao/)
[image]

This same code renders perfectly on other machines. I have seen this problem on other MBPs so I'm confident that it's not a single issue.

Aside from the firmware update, I've not changed anything on this MBP between it working and the artefacts appearing (the code is the same).

If I remove the SSAO effect then the scene renders perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the 'near' property of the camera object to be a value greater than 1. Still unsure why this fixes it but SSAO now works perfectly on the Retina MacBook.

Comment: I expect this is your explanation: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision

Comment: Very interesting! Still curious that this used to work fine with the camera near value set to 1, until a few months ago. Either something changed in Three.js or a Retina MacBook update screwed things up. Still, just glad to have it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take into account the devicePixelRatio. Take a look at this example `http://uihacker.blogspot.gr/2013/03/javascript-antialias-post-processing.html`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't believe it's related to the pixel ratio of the Retina because these SSAO demos worked fine on the same machine a few weeks ago. Something has changed with Three.js or the Retina in those weeks that has caused this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this is happening on all browsers on the Retina Macbook, but appears works on other devices (looks fine on the Chromebook Pixel) suggests that this may be a driver bug on OSX. There may be a way to work around it in WebGL, but I would recommend filing a [bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) at the very least.

Comment: This is what I'm worried it might be, considering the proximity to a recent OS and firmware upgrade to the MBP Retina. I'll submit the bug and continue in the hope of an interim fix.

Interestingly, older SSAO demos work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on a non-retina MacBook Pro, so it seems to be a bug in the NVidia graphics driver. One thing that seems to influence the behavior is the material blending. I get better results with the depthmaterial blending set to THREE.NoBlending:

```
// depth
var depthShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "depthRGBA" ];
var depthUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( depthShader.uniforms );

depthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { fragmentShader: depthShader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: depthShader.vertexShader, uniforms: depthUniforms } );
depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending; //add this
```

Also the near plane setting of the camera seemingly had effect on the rendering.